# Python Cmd library does not work in docker container

Tags: python, docker, alpine-linux

I am trying to dockerize my applications but I am having issues with cmd
[cmd library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html)
When I run my docker I get the cmd prompt but any command afterwards stalls. I don't know if I am supposed to run some shell with it

```
FROM alpine:3.7

RUN apk upgrade \
  && apk add --no-cache --update \
    musl \
    build-base \
    python3 \
    python3-dev \
    postgresql-dev \
    bash \
    git \
  && python3
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
RUN pip3 install virtualenv
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN cd /usr/bin \
  && ln -sf python3 python \
  && ln -sf pip3 pip

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN virtualenv venv
RUN source venv/bin/activate
CMD ["python","test_app/app.py"]
```

---

```
from resource import HelpShell

if __name__ == '__main__':
  tree_shell = HelpShell()
  tree_shell.cmdloop()
```

---

```
from cmd import Cmd

class HelpShell(Cmd):
    intro = 'Type help or ? to list commands.\n'
    prompt = '(bccs>) '

    def do_add(self):
        print('Hello')
```

Comment: I ran the exact same image & python code and the output was Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from resource import HelpShell
ImportError: cannot import name 'HelpShell'

Comment: regardless - you are installing python3 and using python, can you try changing from CMD ["python","test_app/app.py"]
to CMD ["python3","test_app/app.py"]

Comment: Sorry I didn't include the script for resource import HelpShell ImportError.

Comment: It still does not work when I use ["python3","test_app/app.py"] @gCoh